# How to properly kill a _thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I have code:

```
import websocket
import _thread
import time

# Define WebSocket callback functions
def ws_message(ws, message):
    print("WebSocket thread: %s" % message)

def ws_open(ws):
    ws.send('{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"trade"}, "pair":["XBT/USD","XRP/USD"]}')

def ws_thread(*args):
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.kraken.com/", on_open = ws_open, on_message = ws_message)
    ws.run_forever()

# Start a new thread for the WebSocket interface
_thread.start_new_thread(ws_thread, ())

# Continue other (non WebSocket) tasks in the main thread
count=0
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    count+=1
    if count==5
        #stop program
    print("Main thread: %d" % time.time())
```

I'm newbie in websockets and _thread library. I want to stop program after count==5. I tried using sys.exit() but i didn't succeed. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Calling sys.exit() or raising the SystemExit exception is equivalent to calling _thread.exit()

Comment: Well, this does not seem to be equivalent, because sys.exit () did not work for me. However your solution with _thread.exit() worked. Thank you!